# "undefined is not a function" on split with pop

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I have an array of filenames called `ret`.
I want to get the extension of each file name.

```
var cList="";
var fName="";
var ext="";
for(var i=0;i<=ret.length-1;i++){                       
    fName=ret[i];               
    ext=fName.split('.').pop();
    if(ext=="msi"){
        cList+="<br><span class='bld'>Yield Monitor Simulators</span><p>";
    }   
    cList+="<a target='_blank' href='"+httpBase+"cheatsheets/"+fName+"'>"+fName+"</a><br>";
}
```

But on the line:

```
ext=fName.split('.').pop();
```

Why do I get the error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

If I simply remark out the offending line, I get the list of files as expected.

```
var cList="";
var fName="";
var ext="";
for(var i=0;i<=ret.length-1;i++){                       
    fName=ret[i];               
    //ext=fName.split('.').pop();
    if(ext=="msi"){
        cList+="<br><span class='bld'>Yield Monitor Simulators</span><p>";
    }   
    cList+="<a target='_blank' href='"+httpBase+"cheatsheets/"+fName+"'>"+fName+"</a><br>";
}
```

[image]

Still the JSFiddle works so it must be something in my code...

Comment: probably means that whatever value "fname" has is not a string.

Comment: why don't you put `ret` as well?

Comment: that, or the result of the split is null.

Comment: What is ret? Is it an array of strings?

Comment: ret is an array of strings. There are no null values.

Comment: for example:
ret[0]='file1.jpg' 
ret[1]='file2.pdf'

Comment: @BenPotter - Don't think that's a possible return value - if the separator string isn't found, you'll get `[input]`.

Comment: Setting `ret` to an array of strings seems to work fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/cfalk/1pxz73bq/ . Use `console.log` in the loop to make sure `ret` is what you think it is, @Shawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ret is an array containing arrays containing a string...not an array of strings as you expect, check the values of your ret :

```
[] means an array in javascript
["astring"] is an array containing a string
["astring",99] is an array containing a string at index 0 and a number at index 1
```

if you console.log(ret) before your loop you will probably get something like :

```
[["string"],["string"],["string"]...]
instead of ["string","string","string"...]
```

needs some javascript syntax revision here...work hard

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to add toString() to the fName variable.

```
fName=ret[i].toString();
```

apparently a value taken from array of string values is not a string?

added later:

```
for(var i=0;i<=ret.length-1;i++){                   
      console.log(i, ret[i]);
      console.log(i, ret[i], ret[i].split('.'), ret[i].split('.').pop());       
        fName=ret[i].toString();
```

on the first iteration console says:

```
0 ["2020.pdf"] index.js:115
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Comment: no, as said before, before the loop, you should check your ret array  is full of strings only. Then if one value is null or undefined for ex, toString on it will convert it and no more error but...you still have a value which is not a string. In the loop put a log with the index and the string

Comment: A string is a string is a string, and `.toString()` will convert the thing in your array that's *not* a string to a string.

Comment: in the loop, put : console.log(i, ret[i], ret[i].split('.'), ret[i].split('.').pop()); and tell what happens, it will stops at the error index

Comment: @dmidz see addition above. Why isn't "2020.pdf" a string?

Comment: the output of the value ret[i] is exactly ["2020.pdf"] which is an array containing a string, not a string...so ret contains arrays of strings...